# ArcGIS layer to raster or shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, buffer

I downloaded a layer from https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5064154431bf4df5aa444f3b863dfd89

I can add the layer to ArcGIS but I am not sure the file type.

How can I convert this to use a buffer tool on this (like 5-mile buffer from the wetlands)?

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to buffer this resource because it is a Map Image Layer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  That means it can't be converted to polygon or shape file. right?

Comment: No, the best you can manage is to export to a GeoTiff then if you're keen heads-up digitize the boundaries. Check the license arrangements before doing anything though. Your best bet would be to contact the author and request (nicely) the dataset - you might be expected to purchase the data or at the very least sign some sort of licensing agreement crediting the authority on any maps or documents produced from it.